# Cloudera configuration between Master and Slave Nodes

Tags: cloudera, impala, master-slave, kudu

we have three Master nodes and three slave nodes, When we execute the job firstly one master is decided by Round-Robin Method, that one master controls all the slave nodes,
I'm confused about the following
questions:
**1. How we will check that all the slave nodes are connected with all the masters?
2. If one of the Data nodes is down, how can we detect whether our data is decided in the KUDU table or not? and can we extract data from the Kudu table considering KUDU is showing UNHEALTHY Status?
3. If we define 'kudu.num_tablet_replicas' = '1' explicitly in the code then will it overwrite the default configuration of cloudera?**

Can anyone please assist me with the above queries?

We tried to retrieve the data but the tables showed an unhealthy status, so I'm stuck here while losing one of the data nodes.